# Incomplete desktop appears after logging in

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz

When I started my laptop (hp pavillion series with Ubuntu 16.04) this morning, I got the usual login prompt, but when I entered my password and logged in, there was no launcher, no menu, nothing.

I searched for solutions on Ask Ubuntu and got the link to [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

I did the mentioned steps and I got back my launcher only with limited icons and no menu bar. Then, I rebooted my laptop and again the launcher disappeared. So, this is the current status of my laptop.

How can I fix it?

Comment: what version of ubuntu? What did you try before and after the problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: well how the problem arose? what did you do?

Comment: I have done every single steps mentioned in that. It still doesn't work. I was getting a clicking sound beforehand and now the clicking sound stopped and unity is not loading.

Comment: @DeepakKumar was there any problem during installation

Comment: No, I have had this version for almost a year. I have tried the solution in the other answer, I got my launcher back but only half of my icons are there and there is no menu bar appearing and when I rebooted, it all again disappeared.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. This will help us understand what's happening and why the usual recommendations don't work. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I totally understand the procedure of asking questions. When I started my laptop (hp pavillion series with Ubuntu 16.04) this morning, I got the usual login prompt but when i entered my password and logged in, there was no launcher, no menu, nothing. Then, I searched for solutions on askubuntu and got the link to above mentioned post " unity doesn't load...". I did the mentioned steps and I got back my launcher only with limited icons and no menu bar. Then, I rebooted my laptop and again the launcher disappeared. So, this is the current status of my laptop. Please let me know the approach.